# How to have asp:Localize text have italic text?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have this:

```
<asp:localize id="locPopupInfo" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="locPopupInfoRc1" 
    text="Select up to 8 cameras to include." enableviewstate="false"></asp:localize>
```

I want to make the `text` be italic.

I tried adding `style="font-style:italic"` and `style="font:italic"`.  I also tried adding a css:

```
.italic-text{
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Then doing `cssclass="italic-text"` and `class="italic-text"`.

None of these worked.  Is there any way to do this with `asp:Localize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Localize` control inherits from `Literal` control. It does not output any markup itself, just the content in localized manner. Here is what MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it:

> Although the Label control allows you to apply a style to the displayed text, the Localize control does not.

If you want to apply the style nevertheless, here are the options:

1. Switch to `Label` or similar control
2. Wrap in some server-side control, say `Panel`, and apply styling to it
3. Or wrap Localize in a client side tag with style applied. If you are very specific about italic style, you can just do `<i><asp:Localize ...></i>`

Comment: Never mind.  I got it to work.  Marked correct for thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Put your localize into a span and then apply style class onto the span

```
<span class="italic-text">
Your localze stuff ....

</span>
```

To understand localize [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize(v=vs.110).aspx)